# Date Manipulation as a string in python 2.7

Tags: date

I am new to Python.I would like to know how I can manipulate a string that contains the date. For example, I want to transform today's date to the first day of the next year.

For example:

```
07/02/2018 --> 01/01/2019
```

How is that possible in Python 2.7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use datetime package from python. Convert your string in to a date and do the manipulations. See more at here. 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Comment: That helped a lot.Thanks SpawRow!